# Default OS Environ on Local Machine

Tags: python, django, django-settings

I have recently deployed my Django Application to Heorku. However, want to setup some clever way for it to automatically switch to Debug mode when not on Heroku and on my local machine.

Thus far, I have added an environment variable as 'Debug_Flag' (FALSE) to Heorku to trigger the following:

```
DEBUG = os.environ['DEBUG_FLAG']
```

But want to have a it default to True if not found.

Any ideas without using an if statement?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`os.environ`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.environ) is a [Mapping](https://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html#term-mapping), a `dict`-like object. Just use [`get`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get) with a default value:

```
DEBUG = os.environ.get('DEBUG_FLAG', True)
```